# Is there a way to achieve 2-step routing in angular?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm not even sure how to name the problem I have. I'd also like to avoid using secondary routes. I have been trying to create something like 2-step routing in an angular application.

In theory, this is supposed to be nested routing. But I think the assumption is that if you use a componentless route, then the child routes are routed to the parent outlet, which doesn't work. Using the same component in each feature route is solution #2. I'd like to have something in between, which is the same 'wrapper' for all the componentless child routes.

## Outer routing

The outer router has 2 routes:

- `/login`: shows the login component
- everything else should be wrapped in an app shell. The app shell is a component with a sidebar, a navbar, and a router-outlet where all the actual content should go

## Inner routing

The application has multiple feature modules and ideally, each module should define its routes. An example could be the user profile:

- `/profile/settings`: shows the settings inside the shell
- `/profile/account`: shows the account details inside the shell

## Solution 1

Define a common routing module for every module, e.g. `AppRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routers = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '', component: AppShellComponent, children: [...] }
]
```

This restricts me from having proper separation or using features like lazy loading.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-solution1

## Solution 2

Use the `AppShellComponent` on each routing module, e.g. `ProfileRoutingModule`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile', component: AppShellComponent, ... }
]
```

This is closer to the solution, but now I have multiple instances of the AppShellComponent which means extra resources and a reload every time the app navigates from one module to the other.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-solution2

## Solution 3

A component encapsulated both the login and shell components. It knows whether the app has logged in or not and shows the appropriate part of the template. This will be routed to `''`. This defeats the purpose of the solution I'm trying to make.

---

Is there a solution I'm missing? :/

Comment: What are you defining as a "secondary" route?

Comment: A secondary outlet, as defined by angular https://angular.io/guide/router#secondary-routes. This is basically adding a second outlet at the same level as the primary one, e.g. `/login(popup: wrong-password)`

Comment: What do you mean by a 2-step routing? Both your solutions don't make sense. In solution 1 you want to use the same routing file for all modules? Solution 2 you want to use the same component for all routes? Solution 3 sounds like you don't understand how routes work and when to use them. All solutions don't make sense.

Comment: @LogicDev it's really hard to explain a problem you don't know the terminology for, or don't understand fully. I have a very specific problem which has a very specific solution. In solution 1, if I didn't use `loadChildren`, then yes I have to list all children in the same file since only 1 route matches at a time. In solution 2, I still need to wrap every inner page with a shell, so I have to re-use the same component. Solution 3, apparently it's wrong in terms of routing but could solve the problem without routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do want nested routing here; the piece you seem to be missing is using `LoadChildren` to define which children go into the "shell".

Basically, your app routing module would be (Example utilizes lazy loading):

```
 {
    path: '',
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'profile', loadChildren: 'profile/profile.module#ProfileModule' },
        ...
    ],
 },
 {
    path: 'login'
    component: LoginComponent
 }
```

`ShellComponent` then has its own `router-outlet` of course

Comment: Actually that's what I have now. The problem is that the shell children need to live in one routing module,  similar to solution 1.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying there. You don't want multiple routing modules?

Comment: I have a complete example of this here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-communication/tree/master/MH-Take1 and a description of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037127/run-a-service-function-inside-an-angular-routing-module-class/49037606#49037606 And you can see in the github code that I have full feature module/lazy loading support. (Though that is not shown in the SO snippets.)

Comment: @DimitriosK. Why do they have to leave in 1 routing file? Then you should just full paths instead of nested modules or routes. In the same routing module give the full url/path and the component that should be loaded.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm sorry, I saw this on my phone and missed the structure a bit. What I hava is a single `loadChildren` property, not a children array with multiple `loadChildren` entries. Even though the `AppRouting` will need to 'know' all routing entry points, I don't think there's a way around this. Thanks :)

@DeborahK I actually watched your routing course on pluralsight for this exact problem :D

Comment: @DeborahK Sorry, I thought you were Dimitrios when I saw your comment

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem. I tried so many things: bootstrap different modules, different root components, solve it with Router module configuration. For my case it would require to add wrapper shell all feature modules except only one.

At the end I found a simple solution. You can provide as many `router-outlet` as you want in your `AppComponent` but keep only 1 based on some condition. So I made 1 `router-outlet` wrapped with app shell styles and 1 bare for my special case.