# angular 4 - How to hide nav bar container in other components?

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular2-routing, navbar

I want to show navbar container only when navbar component is route and hide for other component of navbar dropdown component. Can anybody help me with this if you don't understand i will make clear to you. Thanks in advance.

accountdashboard.component.html

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Report
                    <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/journalVoucher']">Day Book</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/AccountLedgerView']">Ledger</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/TrialBalance']">Trial Balance</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/SaleBook']">Cash Flow</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/SaleBook']">Fund Flow</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/ProfitLoss']">Profit &amp; Loss</a></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/BalanceSheet']">Balance Sheet</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/SaleBook']">Sales Book</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/SaleBook']">Purchase Book</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/materializedview']">Materialized View</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/accountdashboard/BillReturnView']">BillReturn View</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Hello Angular

Comment: i have navbar.component.html                                                                               <nav> details </nav> and <div> container </div>  i want to show div for navbar.component.html but i don't want to show it in other component even other component using <navbar></navbar>

Comment: I know this questions doesn't sound similar, but the answer may be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037127/run-a-service-function-inside-an-angular-routing-module-class/49037606#49037606

Comment: http://localhost:/accountdashboard      i want to show description for this but i don't want to show for other component like below. if you dont't understand please look upper commments i have clearly defined. 
http://localhost:/accountdashboard/purchase

Comment: if your navbar depends only the url, just subscribe to ActivatedRouter.Url (or ActivatedRouter.params), see https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute, some like show the offical docs about subscribe to paramMap https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route-in-action

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acrmuj

Comment: in .ts file       hideElement = false;  in constructor ->
     this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                if (event.url === '/accountdashboard') {
                    this.hideElement = true;
                } else {
                    this.hideElement = false;
                }
            }
        });  in .html file     <div class="header-wrapper" [hidden]="!hideElement">
    
</div>

Comment: i go the answer. Thanks for support.