# How to load one component without other components beeing displayed

Tags: angular, module, components

I do know the general structure of Angular.
The first file executed is the main.ts file. In this file AppModule is imported. In AppModule the root-component AppComponent is imported. At last the AppComponent is between the body-tag of the index file - the one file which is served by the server.
You can nest components - display one component **alone** may work but I do not understand how.

I have looked it up on google, bought an online course on udemy (but just finished a tiny part) - I did not find a thing. I bet the solution is trivial and I am just bad at looking up things...

Following code is just freestyle-coded to make my problem clear, so there might be no meaning for you guys.

Because of the weird structe of how a question should be written, I write the following file names in order so you know which code belongs to which file.

1.app.component.html

2.nav.component.html

3.content.component.html

4.app-routing.module.ts

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>



<h1>Nav</h1>
 <ul>
   <li><a routerLink="/content">Content</a></li>
 </ul>



 <p>
  content works!
 </p>



const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "content", component: ContentComponent}
];
```

Clicking on the link, content.component.html is displayed but also nav.component.html, which is logical by thinking about the structure but I just want to display the content. Normally the naviagtion is always displayed but this is just an example. So how to only display the content.

This question got huge. Thank you for taking the time to read it and trying to help me!

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are asking, you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037127/run-a-service-function-inside-an-angular-routing-module-class/49037606#49037606

Comment: I will read through it! Thanks for linking!

Comment: You could also simply have `router-outlet` as a single thing rendered in the app-root component. Then everything else comes through routes you've configured. Not a good long-term strategy though, better to have a layout-component with some sort of attached service that handles all this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the structural directive *ngIf
on app.component.html

```
<app-nav *ngIf="condition"></app-nav>
```

where condition will be a boolean variable on app.component.ts when "condition == false" nav component will not be displayed.

[NgIf Documentation angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: I will look what I can do whti ngIf directive regarding my goals!

Comment: The downside of this approach is that *every* page in the application then needs to know about this condition and set it. Otherwise the user may go from say the login page to a detail page and the nav bar won't appear.